# Unable to seal powerwasher leak

Tags: leaking, pressure-washer

My power washer developed a leak which I could not fix with plumber's tape or a new washer this time. I opened it up and removed the spring switch to identify where water leaks from. I don't know how to fix this one.

I tried to apply a silicon sealant which prevented it from leaking when not in use. However after a few seconds of usage it started leaking again.

I don't know which brand this is as it is now 13 years old. Does anyone know how to plug the leak as shown in the photo?

[image]

Comment: Imagine that is the high pressure side, so silicon or tape will not do much good.  13 years probably the parts are worn and need to be replaced for proper sealing.  Might even be able to just get a replacement pump that will fit on the motor.

Comment: There's no builder plate or brand labeling anywhere at all on the machine? Maybe post a full picture of it and someone might recognize it. I'd agree with @crip659 - after 13 years, the high pressure side springs, washers, seals, etc. are simply wearing out and replacement of individual seals or the mechanism in your second pic, or a larger part may be called for. Slathering silicone sealant everywhere sounds like a recipe for _ensuring_ that parts need to be replaced, though.

Comment: if you pull out that "staple" you should be able to remove the leaking part, whether that can be easily corrected (eg replace the O rings)  or needs replacement I can't say.

Comment: I pulled out the staple but nothing budged. I tried pulling the golden threaded part out but it didn't budge. Since its been 13 years I've ordered a new one. Its a pity though, even with the leak its generating fairly decent pressure. 
@FreeMan I will look closely for any branding.

Comment: After 13 years, there's likely to be some corrosion (even on aluminum) holding bits together. Try some penetrating fluid (my favorite is PB Blaster, WD40 will work in a pinch).

Comment: or turn the pump on and extract it by hydraulic pressure.

Comment: Think OP wants to keep that part handy and easy to find.

Comment: A label read "HD Power Washers" but it was vague. I have purchased a replacement Ryobi instead and stripped the old washer for parts. The GFCI plug and machine screws will be useful.  I was unable to remove the leaking part nor seal it with any kind of sealant including super glue (I had to try). After 13 years of service it's time had come - even the oil in the pump had become milky indicating water seepage.